# How to regroup blog posts with multiple categories by category in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have Blog with posts that have multiple categories

```
class BlogDetailPage(Page):
  heading = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
  categories = ParentalManyToManyField("blog.BlogCategory", blank=False)
  ...

class BlogCategory(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
  slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
  ...
```

My posts are as follows:

- Post 1: Category A
- Post 2: Category A, Category B
- Post 3: Category B

I want regroup posts by category as below:

Category A

- Post 1
- Post 2

Category B

- Post 2
- Post 3

My current solution is not giving me correct results.

```
{% regroup posts by categories.all as posts_by_categories %}
    <ul>
        {% for category in posts_by_categories %}
        <li>{{ category.grouper.0 }} # first category name
            <ul>
                {% for post in category.list %}
                <li>{{ post.id }}, {{post.categories.all}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Amy ideas?

Comment: If the answer for the same problem in your previous question was helpful (which steered you in the right direction), please accept it or elaborate further.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to use 'regroup', How about using 'related_name'?

In python

```
class BlogDetailPage(Page):
   categories = ParentalManyToManyField("blog.BlogCategory", blank=False, related_name="blog_posts")
   ...
```

In Django_html

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories.all %}
    <li>{{ category.title }} # first category name
        <ul>
            {% for post in category.blog_posts.all %}
            <li>{{ post.id }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves my issue. I didn't know I could use 'related name this way.